# Can't connect to Gmail SMTP secured with 2FA

Tags: gmail, imap, two-factor-authentication

For some reason, I cannot send an email from my application using Google SMTP protocol. I receive a message that looks like that:

```
1. Unhandled javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
   534-5.7.14
   <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt0
   534-5.7.14
   joZVenRyJq1oMRdChfymgOOgcAmikBwqT-_rFkNsHtvsquevNauUwW34Ksg5n8kXxPTALF
   534-5.7.14
   SYbdpH4O4GEE2TXaQmHScXAY15r_00D-lmyVzoJs54ba6RrOYb-yVcFNpsZbxxonQckTgd
   534-5.7.14
   dxdnp69p7t3_xj5523el2LWvh_HPE2lKTgOr8yLkeXjrFKYhvJT1jRhb5-Sy3Rs3G7OjuS
   534-5.7.14 GdcriEyrrStn9Re4Vq7U46c5f8SwM> Please log in via your
   web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.  534-5.7.14 Learn more
   at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
   c12-v6sm1390727lji.59 - gsmtp
```

Some facts:

- The web interface (gmail.com) works fine;
- I've got 2FA enabled;
- I use a new application password;
- IMAP is enabled in gmail settings, I checked it;
- Another account with 2FA and application password works fine in my app.
- Both accounts are in different Google custom domains. May it affect them somehow?

Code (I use Clojure):

```
(def cred {:host "imap.gmail.com" 
           :user "user@my_domain.net" 
           :pass "application_password" 
           :ssl true})
(send-message cred {:from "test@test.com" 
                    :to "bar@test.me" 
                    :subject "hello" 
                    :body "test"})
```

UPD: I also tried to follow the link from the response. It prompts me for 2FA and then redirects me to my account settings. Sending an email still doesn't work.

Comment: For reference, IMAP in general does not send messages.  You can save messages, but you need to use SMTP to actually send.

Comment: Did you follow the advice to log in via your Web browser (on the same host) and try again?  It looks like Google has blocked you due to unspecified security reasons.

Comment: @Max Sorry it was a copy/paste issue. I still cannot send an email through SMTP. I tried to follow the link in a browser, it asks for 2FA login, then it shows a security dashboard. Nothing has changed so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 8 hours of trying this and that I found an option in Google Apps. Go to Security -> Advanced -> Check "Allow users to manage their security settings" (it was disabled). Now it works, oh gosh.

Comment: is this setting still in the same place?  I can't seem to find the setting. Thanks

Comment: Same, it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure which options the answer Ivan provided is referring to. They don't appear in my non-gapps account perhaps due to a UI update.

I had a similar problem with a nas cage configured to use a Gmail SMTP to send alert emails. Once I enabled 2FA on the Gmail account the emails would fail.

The solution was to create an 'App Password' under the google account security tab. Essentially these are passwords created on a per-app basis for programs/devices that do not support 2FA. Once you create the password, you use it in place of the original Gmail password for that specific app only. Here's a direct link to the [Google Security App Password Page](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)